# Three curtailments

Tags: word, letters

### I.

I can separate two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can separate two high places.

### II.

I can connect two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can connect two high places.

### III.

I can separate two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can connect two high places.

### Notes:

- All of the words are singular nouns.
- "High" is relative.

Hint #1 for III:

> Both are covered by water.

Hint #2 for III:

> I never said you had to remove the *first* letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1

> [v]alley

2

> [b]ridge

3

> [b]lock , [t]rack ,

EDIT for 3 , with the new clue "removing any letter" , which I did not add earlier, assuming that the only first letter had to be removed.

> f[j]ord or f[i]ord

Comment: Wait... what? The third one changes two letters.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes , no, only one letter changes, but I am giving two alternate solutions , with the last comma indicating more possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

I.

I can separate two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can separate two high places.

> valley -> alley (valley can separate mountains, alley is a street which separates rows of potentially high trees)

II.

I can connect two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can connect two high places.

> bridge -> ridge (bridge can connect two trees, cliffs, whatever, a ridge is a connection of mountains in a way)

III.

I can separate two high places.

Remove one letter, and I can connect two high places.

> I am not sure. Maybe swale -> wale? A swale is a bit like a valley and a wale seems to be something like a belt or strap that you could use to connect two high places.

Comment: Thumbs up to the first two.

Answer (score 7):

III.

> Fjord and Ford. A fjord separates the high cliffs on either side. A ford joins the two sides of a river at a passable point. And both are covered with water.

Answer (score 3):

For II, I think it's

> It's BRIDGE and RIDGE

Answer (score 3):

For III could it be

> **Privet** separates houses, and **Rivet** connects the beams in skyscrapers

Comment: Clever! Not what I had in mind, but does kind of work. Also, TIL what that word means.

Answer (score 2):

Huh - for II I was thinking:

> Bridge/Bride, since marriages between royals were often used to cement alliances. However, bridge/ridge does seem to make more sense :)

Comment: that *is* lateral thinking. I like that one.